# How to make a request to an API with Lambda Expression?

Tags: linq, api, asp.net-core, lambda, expression

At my Controller I have the following method:

```
// GET: api/Base
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>>> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> e)
{
    return await items.Where(e).ToListAsync();
}
```

How to make a request to this method and get all items that are Active?

```
(i => i.IsActive())
```

Comment: Short answer is : You can't

Comment: An HTTP request?

Comment: Yes. Something like: 
`using(var client = new HttpClient())
 {
      var response = await client.GetAsync(_someUrl);
 }`